# Standard responses for restful API

Tags: javascript, rest, sails.js, passport.js

I am creating a rest server for my hybrid mobile app to consume and my webserver is currently based on sails. I am implementing various authentication calls using passport and wondering if there is any standard way for the output for calls like login, signup, logout etc.

I found few public apis on the web whose output can be mimicked by me but wondering if a more standard public API output can be used by me.

Comment: I think of login/logout as POST/DELETE of a session. A RESTful response to a POST is a link to the created resource, and possibly returning the session credentials (auth token/whatever) in the response entity. Signup is similar, where you POST a new user.

Comment: What about isAuthenticated and logout?

Comment: isAuthenticated should be a filter returning 403 when trying to access a protected resource, logout is DELETE on the session (returning 200/204 if successful)